# React native: How to use js library from cdn stripe.js

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, cdn

I want to use stripe.js library with React native which is only available with a cdn.

Is it possible to use a js library with a cdn only with react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal was simply to integrate an external JavaScript file in your project, the best way might be to download the file from the CDN manually, or as part of your build process and simply `require`/`import` the local file in your app.

However, for using Stripe in your app, I'd recommend looking for a mobile-specific solution such as [stripe-expo](https://github.com/expo/stripe-expo), or [react-native-payments](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments) with the [react-native-payments-addon-stripe](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments/tree/master/packages/react-native-payments-addon-stripe). The stripe.js library is intended for browser use, and while it may work, mobile-specific SDKs are likely to work better in React Native.

Googling "react native stripe" turns out a few other third-party libraries as well. I haven't personally used any of them, but they may be worth evaluating.

Comment: Hi, I did google react native stripe and looked at what is available. I want to implement stripe connect and be able to create a source from user credit card so I can process payments in the future without the user entering information again and again. Using tipsy-stripe but looks like the createSource method from stripe.js is not implemented... And couldn't find in others libraries too. This is why I'm asking the feasibility to integrate stripe.js directly. Looks like not a good idea according to your statement.

Comment: Actually managed to use tipsy-stripe to create a card token which enables to create a source with stripe php library in the back end!